# Lock free hash table for c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

Does anyone know of an implementation of a lock free hash table in C#? Or can anyone confirm for a fact that at least reads on a HashTable are thread-safe?

Edit:

I can read the documentation, but it's unclear.

"It is thread safe for multi-thread use when only one of the threads perform write (update) operations."

So, the question is, if I have multiple threads, and they all *could* write to the hashtable, I would use the writerlock. However, those same threads also read from the hashtable. Do I need a readerlock on the reads?

Comment: A quick look at the documentation would confirm this- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reads are thread-safe until the collection is modified.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx):

> Hashtable is thread safe for use by
>   multiple reader threads and a single
>   writing thread. It is thread safe for
>   multi-thread use when only one of the
>   threads perform write (update)
>   operations, which allows for lock-free
>   reads provided that the writers are
>   serialized to the Hashtable. To
>   support multiple writers all
>   operations on the Hashtable must be
>   done through the wrapper returned by
>   the Synchronized method, provided that
>   there are no threads reading the
>   Hashtable object.
>
> Enumerating through a collection is
>   intrinsically not a thread safe
>   procedure. Even when a collection is
>   synchronized, other threads can still
>   modify the collection, which causes
>   the enumerator to throw an exception.
>   To guarantee thread safety during
>   enumeration, you can either lock the
>   collection during the entire
>   enumeration or catch the exceptions
>   resulting from changes made by other
>   threads.

Answer (score 3):

I can now answer the first part of this question:

> Does anyone know of an implementation of a lock free hash table in C#?

<s>Having just released an alpha version of one:</s>

https://github.com/hackcraft/HackCraft.LockFree

I have one at https://bitbucket.org/JonHanna/ariadne and https://github.com/hackcraft/Ariadne

Comment: Thanks, it's early days, but that makes for fun for the holidays.

Comment: @JonHanna link is broken. Can you update it? Are you still developing it?

Comment: @gkiko I haven't done anything with it in a while, but it has been improved since I posted this answer (in particular, one of my reasons for writing https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpookilySharp/ is that it let me improve on some of the negative performance impact of common .NET hashing patterns on the sort of linear probing power-of-two tables this uses).

Answer (score 2):

In addition .NET 4.0 is adding a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(VS.100).aspx) to the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace...

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own Lock free hashtable by creating a new one and swapping it every time you modify it - it works well if you don't modify it often. (because it's extremely cheap to read and very expensive to write).

Otherwise, I would recommend using a ReaderWriterLockSlim (assuming you read more than you write) or a Monitor (lock statement) if you write a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use your hash table in conjunction with [ReaderWriterLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx) because of what Orion said.